# Cell of custom tableview using xib file, can not be clicked / selected / tapped

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have tableview and customized cell using swift. below is complete code:

```
class LeftMenuViewController: UIViewController {

    let titles: [String] = ["Home", "Category", "Chat", "notification", "Flagger", "Feedback", "Setting", "Log Out"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let leftmenuView : LeftMenu = LeftMenu()
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "LeftMenuCell", bundle : nil)
        leftmenuView.tableMenu.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        leftmenuView.tableMenu.dataSource = self
        leftmenuView.tableMenu.delegate = self
        leftmenuView.tableMenu.allowsSelection = true
        leftmenuView.tableMenu.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        self.view.addSubview(leftmenuView)
    }
}

extension LeftMenuViewController : UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(tableMenu: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return titles.count
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 40
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
        print("Clicked \(indexPath.row)")
        switch indexPath.row {

        case 0:
            sideMenuViewController?.contentViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: HomeViewController())
            sideMenuViewController?.hideMenuViewController()
            break
        case 1:
            sideMenuViewController?.contentViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController:CategoryViewController())
            sideMenuViewController?.hideMenuViewController()
            break
        default:
            break
        }
    }

    func tableView(tableMenu: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:LeftMenuCell = tableMenu.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! LeftMenuCell
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        cell.menuName.text = titles[indexPath.row]
        cell.menuName.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        return cell
    }
}
```

But I am confused, my cell can not be clicked / tapped. I thought it needs a simple *didDeselectRowAtIndexPath* implementation? Even if I print inside that method, it is not writing out "Clicked".

So whats wrong in my code, can anybody help me?

Thanks

Comment: Did you add `frame` or layout constrains for `leftmenuView`? The view could be visible when `frame` is zero, but have no any interaction.

Comment: please can you explain me ? i tried your answer after this one (Change didDeselectRowAtIndexPath to didSelectRowAtIndexPath) and agree about my typo method, but still not working. can you attach capture or detail of your suggestion ? many thanks

Comment: Try to add

    `override func viewDidLayoutSubviews {
         super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
         leftmenuView.frame = self.view.bounds
    }`

Answer (score 3):

Change `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` to `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

- didSelect is called when the cell is tapped.
- didDeselect is called on the first cell when another cell is selected.

Comment: @Alfarabi `not worked` isn't enough information. Is the console log showing the print out? is the cell showing on the screen in the first place? did anything happen at all? Did the cell highlight / change colour when tapped? have you set the `LeftMenuViewController` as both the `delegate` and `datasource` of the tableView?

Comment: hai [tag:SimonMcLoughlin], i made another post/comment below to complete my problem info thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If didDeselectRowAtIndexPath still not getting called check selection about be single selection , that should not be no selection.

Refer screen shot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

All views should have a non-zero frame. Try to add the next code into `LeftMenuViewController`:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews {
   super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
   leftmenuView.frame = self.view.bounds
}
```

Also it could be the same for `tableView` inside `LeftMenu` but using `layoutSubviews` method.

Comment: yes Sir, 

i made the one xib file called LeftMenu.xib and set it to the LeftMenu : UIView, this class containing @IBOutlet var tableMenu: UITableView!

in my LeftMenuViewController i add that LeftMenu, so i have one subview inside controller now, so i have onwe UiTableView also inside subview

Comment: Horaaayyy.. now its worked, i follow your answer using:
    
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        leftmenuView.frame = self.view.bounds       
}
the result page left menu is more worst, now my menu moving to right location, but ok thats another problem to me to trial error :D. thanks [tag:AndrewBogaevskyi]

Comment: Of course you could set and frame you want with `CGRectMake()`